# How can I get a certern link's position not in rviz?

Tags: ros, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want write a certern link position(x,y,z) to a txt file.Which function do i need? Where does the date of link's position store?THX!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257692/how-can-i-get-a-certern-link%27s-position-not-in-rviz?/) by [Ddj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29459/ddj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have joint state information being published, you have a URDF, and you have the `robot_state_publisher` running then you should be able to visualize the pose of the robot in rviz. If all of that is working, to obtain the position of a particular link, all you need to do is create a [tf listener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2) and lookup the transform between some inertial frame and a frame on the link that you are interested in. This can easily be done in Python (tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29)) or C++ (tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)).

The `robot_state_publisher` subscribes to joint state information and looks at a robot's URDF on the parameter server. With those two pieces of information, it can publish the relevant `/tf` data so that the full pose of the robot can be known by any ROS node (including rviz and your own listener).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0